# Best PHP encryption/encoding method to use the output as folder name

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, directory, special-characters

I have some text less than 18 char. I want to make a directory using this text as directory name . 
Some time the text will have special character such as á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡, ? so that it cannot be use as a directory name

So, I think it is better to encrypt or encode the test so that it can be used us folder name

which is the best encryption/encoding method for my acquirement?

Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [base64](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) encoding if you care about re extracting the original folder name:

```
base64_encode('Folder Name');   // results: Rm9sZGVyIE5hbWU=
```

If you don't want to get the original name back, you can just use [MD5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php):

```
md5('Folder Name');   // results: d89dbf99916d31a7870474d44d481ffa
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a hash, simply go for [`md5()`](http://php.net/function.md5) as it's ultra-fast and you don't need anything that's cryptographically strong.

Or you can easily clean the string, here's my method:

```
/**
 * Sanitizes a filename, replacing whitespace with dashes and transforming the string to lowercase.
 *
 * Removes special characters that are illegal in filenames on certain operating systems and special characters
 * requiring special escaping to manipulate at the command line. Replaces spaces and consecutive dashes with a single
 * dash. Trims period, dash und underscore from beginning and end of filename.
 *
 * @param string $filename
 *   The filename to be sanitized.
 * @return string
 *   The sanitized filename.
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 *   If <var>$filename</var> is invalid.
 */
final public static function sanitizeFilename($filename) {
  if (empty($filename)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("A file's name cannot be empty.");
  }

  // Remove characters which aren't allowed in filenames.
  $filename = str_replace([ "?", "[", "]", "/", "\\", "=", "<", ">", ":", ";", ",", "'", '"', "&", "$", "#", "*", "(", ")", "|", "~" ], "", $filename);

  // Replace whitespace characters with dashes.
  $filename = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", "-", $filename);

  // Remove characters which aren't allowed at the beginning and end of a filename.
  $filename = trim($filename, ".-_");

  // Always lowercase all filenames for better compatibility.
  return mb_strtolower($filename);
}
```